# HttpClient check valid image file async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-2, httpclient

Am I misusing the HttpClient class incorrectly. I am trying to test the HTTP status of images and it seems to not be executing at all. I have a list of a complex object so I want to run test on all image urls to see which urls are broken by doing  this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var tasks = ObjectViewModel.Select(a => a.UserUrl).Select(url =>   
client.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(t =>
{
  var response = t.Result;
   if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   url = "/Content/Images/MissingPic.png";
 }));
```

I was originally doing it this in a foreach loop like so:

```
foreach(var Model in ObjectViewModel)
{
 Model.UserUrl= Model.UserUrl.GetHttpRequest() ? Model.UserUrl: 
"/Content/Images/MissingImage.png";
 //Model.state= Model.state.ValidName();// this line is something seperate
 //Model.property= Model.state.propertyCheck();// this line is something seperate

}

public static bool GetHttpRequest(this string s)
{
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
                                       .Create(s);
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        HttpStatusCode responseStatusCode;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            responseStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            responseStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
        }
        if (responseStatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

which works perfectly fine, but takes about 5 to 7 seconds to complete all items since they are all running separately which is very long for a request to respond to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using AsParallel() while iterating over your enumeration, should speed it up considerably.

```
var UrlToReponseMap = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
ObjectViewModel.AsParallel().ForAll(x =>
{
  UrlToReponseMap[x.UserUrl] = x.UserUrl.GetHttpRequest();
});
```

Comment: Isn't that what the GetAsync on httpclient is doing? Also placing AsParallel where?

Comment: I went with the Parallel.ForEach but this definetly put me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Linq is (generally) lazy. This means that Linq statements only represent a query. Work happens when you enumerate the query (materialize).

You never materialize your `tasks` query. To get it to actually run the code in your select statement, you need to materialize the query by causing it to be enumerated.

One way would be to simply call `tasks.ToList()`

Comment: Ok now it seems like it actually runs but the broken urls are not being replaced